# I'm trying to make a program that takes a number from the user and determine if this is a prime number by returning prime factors

Tags: python, math, numbers

I'm trying to make a program that takes a number from the user and determine if this is a prime number by returning prime factors

i tried setting an empty array and then making a for loop and append evey number that can be divider by the user input but i always get an empty string in output

`

```
user_number = input('choose your number: ')
number_dividers = []

for x in range(1,int(user_number)) :
    if x % int(user_number) == 0 and x != int(user_number) :
        number_dividers.append(x)
    elif int(user_number) < 1 :
        print('please enter a number higher than 0')


print(number_dividers)
```

`

Comment: Try that by hand with, say, number = 5. You will soon understand.

Comment: nothing changed i still get an empty string

Comment: aaaaaaah ok ok i just figured out i was dividing x by the user input intead of dividing the number by x

Answer (score 0):

To check if the number is prime, you will have to divide 'user_number' by x as opposite of what you've done in the code.

if **int(user_number) % x** == 0 and x != int(user_number) :

Also consider the final statements as -

elif int(user_number) < 2 :

```
    print('please enter a number higher than 1')
```

This is because the conditions in your code will give 1 as a prime number. One is neither prime nor composite so the suggested case should avoid that error.